# How can I swap keys and values in NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, foundation

I want to know how to invert a NSDictionary.

I've seen some crazy code like

```
NSDictionary *dict = ...;
NSDictionary *swapped  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:dict.allKeys forKeys:dict.allValues];
```

which is according to documentation not safe at all since the order of `allValues` and `allKeys` is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSDictionary *dict = ...;    
NSMutableDictionary *swapped = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
    swapped[value] = key;
}];
```

Note that the values should also conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

Answer (score 5):

You're right, that code is crazy, but there are two ways to get an array of the values in the order given by an array of keys:

```
NSArray * keys = [dict allKeys];
NSArray * vals = [dict objectsForKeys:keys notFoundMarker:nil];

NSDictionary * inverseDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:keys
                                                         forKeys:vals];
```

Or

```
NSUInteger count = [dict count];
id keys[count];
id vals[count];
[dict getObjects:vals andKeys:keys];

NSDictionary * inverseDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:keys
                                                         forKeys:vals
                                                           count:count];
```

The former is obviously a lot nicer. As noted [in hfossli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32243456/603977), the objects that were values in the original dictionary must conform to `NSCopying` in order to be used as keys in the inversion.

Comment: Will these solutions work if the Values in the original dictionary (to become keys in the inverted dictionary) are not unique? I never tested the specific initializer under this constraint (having several recurring keys).